# Overriding the back button of super class activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, salesforce

I am integrating with a salesforce android sdk, which has the class nativemainactivty, which extends activity class.

In order to integrate salesforce in to the app, we need to have class which extends nativemainactivity. I implemented it so that when I press back on the phone, it takes the user out of the application. But, I want to navigate to the previous screen. To navigate I override the onBackpressed with below code, but I'm having no success. If any body knows, can you please guide me to achieve this?

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){
  super.onBackPressed() 
  sop("back pressed!!");
}
```

Comment: What happens with that code when you click Back button? Still exits from the app ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the salesforce SDK, but I try to help. In their nativemainactivity they may have overriden the onKeyDown() method. This method calls onBackPressed(). They may catch the back button keycode and don't call the super method of the Activity class.

Try to override following method:

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // do something
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay, nativemainactivity does not override the backpressed and above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are missing the semicolon :

```
  super.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the semicolon that is your issue.

Calling super.onBackPressed() is calling the method for the default behavior of the back button (i.e. exiting the app), which isn't what you want!!

Although there are a number of callbacks in android that require the superclass method to be called in order to function properly, this is not one of them

If you remove the "super.onBackPressed()" from your code and fill the method body in with only the new functionality you wish the back key to have, then it will work:

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){
  sop("back pressed!!");
  //or whatever else you want it to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the things worked.

only thing to do is

remove the moveTaskToBack(true);

in the LoginActivity of salesforce sdk.